# How to use IgnoreCase in multiple condition

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I am new member of this site and Thank you stackoverflwo
Well, I have a program to do which is:

**Create a program the will find and display whether the entered character is a vowel, consonant, digit, or special character.**

And Here my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
    char num = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

    if ((num >= 'A' && num <= 'Z') || (num >= 'a' && num <= 'z')) {
        if (num == 'a' || num == 'e' || num == 'i' || num == 'o'
                || num == 'u' || num == 'A' || num == 'E' || num == 'I'
                || num == 'O' || num == 'U') {
            System.out.println(" vowel");

        } else {
            System.out.println(" consonants");

        }

    } else if (num == '0' || num == '1' || num == '2' || num == '3'
            || num == '4' || num == '6' || num == '7' || num == '8'
            || num == '9') {
        System.out.println(" digits");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Special Character!");
    }
```

My question is how could I use IgnoreCase in my conditional statement to make it simple?

```
if ((num >= 'A' && num <= 'Z') || (num >= 'a' && num <= 'z'))
and
if (num == 'a' || num == 'e' || num == 'i' || num == 'o'
                    || num == 'u' || num == 'A' || num == 'E' || num == 'I'
                    || num == 'O' || num == 'U')
```

Is it possible to make a new statement that has IgnoreCase? because my code looks not simple and its so long

Comment: you can use ASCII values for condition. one condition for all the numbers other for characters then internally you can distinguish vowels and consonants.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need all of these comparisons, you can simply use [`Character#toLowerCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase-char-):

```
num.toLowerCase() == 'a' || ...
```

You also might want to consider using loops.

Comment: Thank you but in these code:
if ((num >= 'A' && num <= 'Z') || (num >= 'a' && num <= 'z'))

can i use that?

Comment: @jAvAtHeGamer Maybe it's better for you to use regex here

Answer (score 1):

Maroun gave your answer, perhaps you can just use

```
public static boolean isTestPassed(char num) {
  return "0123456789AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(num) != -1; // 
}
```